# Align a selectizeInput and two actionButtons horizontally

Tags: r, shiny

This is a snippet of my interface (if `choices = c()` it means that the choice is managed on the server side):

```
sidebarPanel(
    selectizeInput(
        "s1",
        "Select s1",
        choices = c(),
        multiple = FALSE
    ),
    div(style = "margin-top:-15px"),
    radioButtons(
        "r1",
        "Select r1",
        choices = c("A", "B", "C")
    ),
    div(style = "margin-top:-15px"),
    selectizeInput(
        "s2",
        "Select s2",
        choices = c(),
        multiple = FALSE
    ),
    div(style = "margin-top:-15px"),
    selectizeInput(
        "s3",
        "Select s3",
        choices = c(),
        multiple = TRUE
    ),
    div(style = "margin-top:-15px"),
    actionButton(
        "b1",
        "Enter"
    ),
    actionButton(
        "b2",
        "Enter"
    ),
    div(style = "margin-top:-15px"),
    selectizeInput(
        "s4",
        "Select s4",
        choices = c(),
        multiple = FALSE
    )
)
```

My question is:
How can I arrange the selectizeInput `s3` and the actionButtons `b1` and `b2` all on the same line horizontally?

Answer (score 2):

You can add columns in a fluid row:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    fluidRow(
      column(
        width = 4,
        selectizeInput(
        "s3",
        "Select s3",
        choices = c(),
        multiple = TRUE,
      )),
      div(style = "margin-top:45px"),
      column(
        width = 4,
        actionButton("b1","Enter")
      ),
      div(style = "margin-top:45px"),
      column(
        width = 4,
        actionButton("b2","Enter")
      )
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

The action buttons do not have a title so they need to be pushed downwards e.g. using `margin-top` to align the buttons with the text input box.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm using a `width = 10` for the selectizeInput, and `width = 1` for each actionButton. But so the second button goes over the right edge of the sidebarPanel. I would like the right edge of the second button to be aligned with the end of the previous selectizeInput, i.e. `s2`. Is it possible?